# The type ' ' has no constructors defined C#

Tags: c#, constructor, defined, steambot

I'm trying to call a method from another cs file. I have created the new instance of the class that the method resides in, but get this error:

> The type 'SteamKit2.SteamFriends' has no constructors defined

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

The class in which i'm trying to call this method from is as follows

```
using System;
using SteamKit2;
using SteamTrade;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SteamBot;

namespace SteamBot
{
public class HarvesterHandler : UserHandler
{
    public int FriendCount = 0;
    public int FriendToTrade = 0;
    SteamFriends me = new SteamFriends(); 

    public override void OnLoginCompleted()
    {
        FriendCount = me.GetFriendCount();
        if (FriendToTrade < FriendCount)
        {
            Bot.SteamTrade.Trade(me.GetFriendByIndex(FriendToTrade));
            Log.Info("Sending Trade Request to Friend " + FriendToTrade + " of " + FriendCount);
            return;
        }
        while (true)
        {
            Log.Warn("Finished trading");
        }
    }
}
}
```

The referred class is as follows (in a separate cs file)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SteamKit2.Internal;

namespace SteamKit2
{
public sealed partial class SteamFriends : ClientMsgHandler
{
    object listLock = new object();
    List<SteamID> friendList;
    List<SteamID> clanList;

    AccountCache cache;


    internal SteamFriends()
    {
        friendList = new List<SteamID>();
        clanList = new List<SteamID>();

        cache = new AccountCache();
    }
    public int GetFriendCount()
    {
        lock ( listLock )
        {
            return friendList.Count;
        }
    }
    public SteamID GetFriendByIndex( int index )
    {
        lock ( listLock )
        {
            if ( index < 0 || index >= friendList.Count )
                return 0;

            return friendList[ index ];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try to make the constructor `public` instead of `internal`

Answer (score 1):

the constructor is defined as internal. And therefore it is only accessible from the same assembly. Probably this constructor is only intended to be called by a factory? Is SteamFriends realy in the same project as HarvesterHandler?

Comment: Given the name of the namespace, I would bet that this is the case.

Comment: Oh wait, no they're not in the same project. Same solution, not the same project

Comment: Ok there is the Problem. Internal is only visible inside the same assembly -> same project

Comment: Probably you have the code in another project, but you accidentally link to a other referenced assembly instead the other project? Have a look at your references

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot), correct?

I'm not sure the purpose of this line:

```
SteamFriends me = new SteamFriends();
```

Everything you need in your individual Handler is available in the `Bot` instance. For `SteamFriends` related information look in `Bot.SteamFriends` (see the [SimpleUserHandler](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/blob/master/SteamBot/SimpleUserHandler.cs) for some examples)

Related to your question, I can provide an alternative for you, since I am not sure why the `GetFriendByIndex` is not working properly without spending more time troubleshooting the project.

You can loop through the entire Friend list of the bot (which has a maximum of 250 possible friends, if I'm remembering limits on the Valve system correctly) by doing something like this:

```
foreach (Bot.SteamFriends.FriendsListCallback.Friend friend in callback.FriendList)
{
    // Check the friend ID (Steam Profile ID - 64bit number) against what who you want to trade
    if (friend.SteamID == "VALUE YOU ARE EXPECTING")
    {
        Bot.SteamTrade.Trade(friend);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make all method static in SteamFriends class and then access from the class name with classname.
Surely you will get the problem solution.
like-:

```
public static int GetFriendCount()
    {
        lock ( listLock )
        {
            return friendList.Count;
        }
    }
    public  static SteamID GetFriendByIndex( int index )
    {
        lock ( listLock )
        {
            if ( index < 0 || index >= friendList.Count )
                return 0;

            return friendList[ index ];
        }
    }
```

and access from HarvesterHandler  cs file .
don't make an object of the class.

 **FriendCount = SteamFriends.GetFriendCount();..**

Cheers !..

Answer (score -1):

It is because the accessibility of the parameterless constructor is set to internal change :

```
internal SteamFriends()
```

to

```
public SteamFriends()
```

Comment: Questionable answer, the constructor of `SteamFriends` probably was defined as `internal` for a reason.